# Deployment keys are empty appcenter code push cli

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, react-native-code-push

Im trying to retrieve code push deployment keys using this command:

`appcenter codepush deployment list -a <name/appName> --displayKeys`

it return an empty table :

[image]

Ios/Android apps were added to appcenter console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My bad I forgot to activate codePush in Distribute panel in appcenter.